# TypeError when editing new page or post

Tags: javascript

The site in question is running WordPress 6.4.2, PHP 8.1. I am getting this error when I attempt to edit a new page or post:

```
TypeError: l(...).sortable is not a function
    at Object.init (...example.com/wp-admin/js/postbox.min.js?ver=6.4.2:2:3686)
    at Object.add_postbox_toggles (...example.com/wp-admin/js/postbox.min.js?ver=6.4.2:2:2725)
    at ...example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/edit-post.min.js?ver=6720d8a86f225f3ce492:7:34281
    at ...example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2:12464
    at ...example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/redux-routine.min.js?ver=0be1b2a6a79703e28531:9:750
    at ...example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2:11537
    at Object.dispatch (...example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2:12407)
    at Object.initializeMetaBoxes (...example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2:17629)
    at ...example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/edit-post.min.js?ver=6720d8a86f225f3ce492:7:101464
    at Ur (...example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:73411)
```

Comment: is this the entire stack trace?